# What is the equivalent of Puppetboard in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I would like to have an overview of all facts of all nodes in the cluster that are provisioned with ansible like [Puppetboard](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppetboard) is doing for all nodes that are provisioned using Puppet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [ansible-cmdb](https://github.com/fboender/ansible-cmdb) ?

It is of course different in many ways, but maybe it serves your use case.